# error prop in Material UI date picker evalutes to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-datepicker

I've created a date picker that uses Jalali calendar.

I tried to pass error checking and using `error` prop in this code below:

```
   <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterJalali}>
      <MobileDatePicker
        label={label}
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
          onChange({
            label: new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fa-u-ca-persian-nu-latn", {
              dateStyle: "short",
            }).format(newValue),
          });
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            color="colorPrimer"
            {...params}
            fullWidth
            sx={{ marginBlock: "1em" }}
            error={errors && !!errors[name]}
            helperText={errors && errors[name] ? `فیلد ${label} را پرکنید` : ""}
          />
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

but get this error:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(InputBase)`, expected `boolean`.
```

I'm really confused, I was sure that this code will evaluate to `boolean`

```
            error={errors && !!errors[name]}
```

and I tried to change it like this

```
  error={!!(errors && errors[name])}
```

but it gave the same result

I used same thing in normal `TextField` component and it is working, I don't know what is different in this.

I would be thankful if you help.

Comment: What does `params` look like?

Comment: @paddotk it comes from material ui itself. it is not my parameters. I console logged it and it gave me this: 

`{
  "label": "زمان حضور",
  "ref": null,
  "error": false,
  "InputProps": {
    "readOnly": true
  },
  "inputProps": {
    "readOnly": true,
    "aria-readonly": true,
    "aria-label": "Choose date, selected date is 1-ام فروردین 1402",
    "value": "1402/01/01"
  }
}
`

Comment: You have two inputProps/InputProps objects in it...

Comment: @paddotk I did such thing. now I have one prop. it doesn't work: 

` 
renderInput={({ error, InputProps, ...params }) => (
          <TextField
            color="colorPrimer"
            fullWidth
            sx={{ marginBlock: "1em" }}
            error={errors && !!errors[name]}
            helperText={errors && errors[name] ? فیلد ${label} را پرکنید: ""}
            {...params}
          />
        )}

`

Answer (score 0):

which version do you use?
please check the following one for more.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-driscoll-gkyjiw?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).